# Whether DDL Commands on Child Table will affect its Parent Table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

In MySQL (5.5) that uses innoDB storage engine, if a column is added/deleted in a child table (that column is not a foreign key reference to the parent table) will it affect the parent table as well? If so, how and if not, why?

**Example:**

Parent Table: Vehicle
Child Table: Car

Assume that Car has some Columns, (say, vehicle_id, car_type) where vehicle_id references Vehicle.

Now, if I add a new Column in Car Table (say car_driver), will it affect the parent table Vehicle in any manner (SELECTs, INSERTs, UPDATEs or DELETEs)?

Both the tables will have at-least 10 Million rows.

(When we had such a scenario, there were some select queries to the parent table while we executed SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST) and we were sure that no external queries were fired on parent table)

Comment: Operations on a child table never have any effect on the parent table. The only operations that have effects across tables are removing/changing foreign keys inthe parent table, if the foreign key has `CASCADE` or `UPDATE` specified.